# simplemembership in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

I have MVC4 application which runs on simplemembership as an authentication. I want to upgrade my developing environment to VS2013 and MVC5. However I found that MVC5 does not support simplemembership as their default authentication. How do I set up my Simplemembership on MVC5? I cannot use 'ASP.NET identity' since I already use dotconnect postgres as my dataProvider. Please give me some advice.

Comment: and the downvoting is because...?

Comment: can you provide proof of investigation, code & what you've tried already - that may explain the down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an article on how to upgrade an MVC4 application using SimpleMembership to MVC5](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/upgrading-web-application-using.html). It includes links to source code.

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.NET implementation of ASP.NET Identity support is added in the latest (7.3) version of dotConnect for PostgreSQL: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29099.

Documentation:

- [Using ADO.NET Implementation of ASP.NET Identity for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Identity-Tutorial.html)
- [Using Entity Framework Implementation of ASP.NET Identity for PostgreSQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Identity-Tutorial-Entity.html)